# My surface pro 7 can't find bootable operating system after I installed ubuntu on USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, usb

Looking for help here. Reference to the subject above I think did something wrong during the process of installing ubuntu on USB so could possibly mistakenly altered the main-drive  partition without knowing and without doing the proper way reverse to it.

After restart my laptop, my surface pro 7 can't boot to windows 11.

[image]

to provide more info, I inserted my ubuntu usb, and screengrab disk info:

[image]

Please let me know is there anything else i should provide here in order to rescue my pc boot to windows properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

From the image you shared, it seems that, apparently, you deleted the entire disk partition table. The only way I see to resolve this problem is something like this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-recover-partition-table-in-linux BUT it's something VERY technical and potentially dangerous. I suggest you to ask for help to a proper Linux expert to help you do that, if you care about your Win11 data. If you don't care about the data you can always reinstall Win11 from an USB pen since the license is usually written in the bios and so, it should be safe.

PS: the disk is very small. I suggest you to use it only for Win11 and choose another pc for a dual boot system since you risk to fill the disk very quickly (Windows can be very resource hungry...).

Comment: thanks. tried but i can't solve the problem

Comment: Remember that when you reinstall Windows from scratch, you have to delete manually all the partitions during the installation process...